# What is the correct approach for Google social authentication in a node.js REST API?

Tags: android, node.js, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-authentication

I am working on a two-tier application where my back-end is a nodeJs (express) REST API server and the front-end is an Android client application (later a web application as well).

I would like to implement registration and authentication with Google accounts but I am not exactly sure what the best approach is.

What I want to achieve is that users could sign up with their Google account, so the server would create a user based their the Google profile data (email, username). Then later the users could log-in with their Google account.

(Logging in in my case means that the the client app would receive a JWT token from the server, signed with user email and user ID. Then the client would send the JWT as a bearer token in every request. Therefore my server is not using sessions.)

I got that far that I can get the OAuth access token of a specific user and use it to get the profile information from GoogleAPIs. (I am planning to do that from the server. Is there a reason to do it from the client app instead?)
I can create an application user with this information and save it in the database together with the access token. No problems this far.

What I am unsure about is how to authenticate ("sign in") the user later.

My thoughts are: 
When users opens the client (Android) app later, they may or may not still have the access token. 
If they have it, no problem, they can send the token to the server and the server can find the user in the database with the same token.
But if the client don't have the token anymore it has to get a new one and send that one to the server.
This case the server will not find a user with that token, but have to ask for the profile information form Google APIs again. Then using the the profile information it can look for a user with the same email.

This should work, but is this the right way of doing it?

Comment: You are misunderstanding Google OAuth a bit. First, if you use two-legged oauth (meaning at the client) you do not get a Refresh Token. You want to do three-legged oauth (meaning at the server) so that you get Access Token, Refresh Token and ID Token. Access Tokens expire in 3600 seconds (usually) so saving them long term is not important. You want to save the Refresh Token which can then recreate the other two tokens. Hit the books and study some more. There is a lot more to know to do this correctly.  https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer

Comment: I read that exact link before. I thought I do not need the offline access type (refresh token) because I only need the profile info once (when I create the user).
But even if I store the refresh token, and my server can ask for new access token, how the users (from the client) will authenticate themselves?

Comment: Meanwhile, reading some more about OAuth and Android authentication, I figured out two things, that can help my cause.
One is that, I can use the OAuth Id token (received from the Google APIs together with the access token) to straight up get the user profile info.
The other thing is that I could save the JWT (that I use for authentication) in shared preferences on my Android app. This way the user can stay logged in util the JWT expires.

Comment: Partially correct. You can save the Refresh Token at the server (never at the client). The Refresh Token can be used to recreate the Access Token and ID Token. JWT is just a technology. Think in terms of one of the three tokens and not how they are formatted. The ID Token also expires or the user might change their information. Do not assume that the ID Token does not change. When you have a specific coding question come back and create a new question.